# Possible to extend multiple views in Backbone?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, backbone-views

I have 3 backbone views (`Month`, `Day`, `Week`).

There is some common code all 3 share that I'll put in a `Base` view.

Then there is some common code that `Day` & `Month` share which I'll put in a `DayAndMonthBase` view and other common code that `Day` & `Week` share which I'll put in a `DayAndWeekBase` view. Both the `DayAndMonthBase` and the `DayAndWeekBase` will extend the `Base`.

Finally, my `Month` view will extend `DayAndMonthBase` and my `Week` view will extend my `DayAndWeekBase`. However with my `Day` view, how can I extend BOTH the `DayAndMonthBase` view as well as the `DayAndWeekBase` view?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I like to solve this sort of problem using mixins rather than inheritance, because there is no clear hierarchical structure here.  Constructs like `DayAndMonthBase` along with `DayAndWeekBase` are rigid and inextensible. What i like to do is define the common behavior as objects, and then inject the behavior into the views using `_.extend` and not `Backbone.View.extend`.

Define your mixin objects

```
var mixin1 = {
    ....
}

var mixin2 = {
    ....
}

var mixin3 = {
    ....
}
```

Then inject these mixins into each View that needs the functionality.

```
var Day = Backbone.View.extend({
    ....
})
_.extend(Day.prototype, mixin1);
_.extend(Day.prototype, mixin2);
_.extend(Day.prototype, mixin3);


var Week = Backbone.View.extend({
    ....
})
_.extend(Week.prototype, mixin1);


var Month = Backbone.View.extend({
    ....
})
_.extend(Month.prototype, mixin2);
```

It's easier to reason about this way, because you don't have the mental load of remembering what `DayAndWeekBase` actually does. If you name your mixins appropriately, it's clear to see what kind of functionality you're injecting into the views.